# Custom UIButton not showing on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7

I have a custom UIButton like this:

```
_facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_facebookButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(buttonFacebookPressed:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    [_facebookButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookInactive"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [_facebookButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookInactive"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

_facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 33.0, 33.0);
_facebookButton.center = CGPointMake(60, 48);

_facebookButton.alpha = 0;
[_subView addSubview:_facebookButton];
```

It is in a UITableViewCell and on the simulator it looks OK, but on the actual device it is gone. I've searched the internet and they are always talking about image names which are not correct. I use the xcasset and have an image set named: facebookInactive.

[image]

Why is the button not showing up on the device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry i don't understand why button.alpha = 0?

Comment: Because the button becomes visible with an animation as soon as the user presses on something ;-)

Comment: ahh ok! I can suggest how to test, pass a backgroundColor to the button instead of the image? and see if you see the button on the device

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. In simulator I can see the background, on the device the button is still not visible... :( I also removed the alpha = 0, also no difference... No log is written or nothing, no Issues according to xCode so I don't understand what is going wrong :S

Comment: try to remove button.center..

Comment: Nope no difference...

Comment: and if change with: _facebookButton = [[UIButton alloc] init]; ?

Comment: Ok I found the issue... The button had a weak pointer, changed it to strong and now they are visible... :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about that,
          ios Setting -> Facebook -> Sign in Process is completely registered ?

this may helpful to you.

Thanks & Regards,
Rushik Thumar.

Comment: Yes, but also if it isn't, the same button image is used so that shouldn't make a difference... That's why in this case I added the same line in the IF statement just to rule out such things...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the statement

```
_facebookButton.alpha = 0;
```

or replace it with

```
_facebookButton.alpha = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can goto your project in Project Navigator then 
select your Project -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle resourses and check that their is ".xcasset" avilable.

if No then click on "+" icon & add ".xcasset"

Now build & Run.